# How to lookup range value from database

Tags: php, mysql

How to find a value based on a range stored in the database.

My `friend_levels` table:

[image]

and on my `profile` table:

[image]

When I have `friend_points = 1`, I will get *Normal Rate*, then if I had `friend_points = 180` I will get *Great Friend*, so it's basically like this on programming

```
if($profile_points >= 0 && $profile_points < 50) {
    return 'Normal Rate';
} else if($profile_points >= 50 && $profile_points < 100) {
    return 'Friend';
} else if($profile_points >= 100 && $profile_points < 150) {
    return 'Good Friend';
}....
```

my question too is does it possible on QUERY? or I just make it on the PHP?

**EDIT1**: Is there a way to get the next target value?
For ex. If I'm on the `Friend rate with 68 points` how to get the `100 = Good Friend` ? nevermind the substraction, I just want to get the next row.

[image]

Comment: What is the relations between the table? 'POINTS = 1' what column is this? points needed? or friend_points?

Comment: yeah it's `friend_points`, so basically it's like `experience` from some games, if you reach that points you will level up into `Normal > Friend > Good > Great`

Comment: Yes, I understood what you need, but what column specify how much points he have??? and friends_level.id = profile.user_id ?

Comment: no, ignore the `user_id` part, it's just foreign key of my `users` table, those two table have no relation.

Comment: So?... you are ignoring all of my questions

Comment: @StormSpirit, do mention foreign key in the profile table as asked by  sagi

Comment: I just create a table, so when I want to upgrade more, I will add more `friend_levels` so it will use that directly without changing code, only on the ADMIN UI.

Comment: @StormSpirit I've edited my answer, look now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can use CASE EXPRESSION like this:

```
SELECT id,user_id,
       case when friend_points between 0 and 49 then 'Normal rate'
            when friend_points between 50 and 99 then 'Friend'
            when friend_points between 100 and 149 then 'Good friend'
            .......
       end as 'Friend_Status'
FROM profile
```

**EDIT:**

Or, if this names can change dynamicly then with a join:

```
SELECT t.id,t.user_id,s.name
FROM profile t
INNER JOIN friend_levels s ON(t.friend_points >= s.points_needed)
WHERE s.points_needed = (select min(f.points_needed)
                         from friend_levels f
                         where t.friend_points >= f.points_needed)
```

Comment: is there a way to make it dynamically? so when I add more `friend_levels` with higher `points_needed`, it will case directly

Comment: @StormSpirit if the friend_levels become dynamic then you have to make the case portion of the query also dynamic or else how.

Comment: @StormSpirit I've edited my answer, the second query suppose to be dynamic and will work for all the table

Comment: cause when I used `min`, it stays on the lowest level, instead his current level.

Comment: You are right, my bad, should be max.. @StormSpirit

Comment: @StormSpirit it is customary to open a new question after a question has already been answered.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Comment: @sagi it's still connect though. Please need help, just that.

Comment: Yes its connect but its not as simple as you think it is, so it will be complex and right now I'm going out.. So I'm saying this for you.. open a new question and they will answer it:) just copy the progress to the new question @StormSpirit

Answer (score 0):

next smallest point

```
SELECT MAX (DISTINCT points_needed) 
FROM friend_levels
WHERE points_needed < =$profile_points;
```

next highest point

```
SELECT MIN (DISTINCT points_needed) 
FROM friend_levels
WHERE points_needed > $profile_points;
```

Answer (score 0):

The CASE method proposed by Sagi works, but means that you need to update your code (SQL in this case rather than PHP) if you want to change your ranges.

Safin's method is only part of a solution - in order to find the corresponding description, Safin's query needs to be embedded in a select with joins/subselects as per Sagi's update, but this is somewhat inefficient.

Personally I wouldn't use aggregation for this:

```
SELECT user_id, 
(SELECT fl.name
   FROM friends_level fl
   WHERE fl.points_needed<profiles.friend_points
   ORDER BY fl.point_needed DESC
   LIMIT 0,1) as level
FROM profiles
```