# How to get the next value from inner join SQL

Tags: mysql

This question is continue of this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35410072/5406008), since they don't want to answer without opening new.

This is my tables:

**customer_profiles**

[image]

**friend_levels**

[image]

so I have a query that get what level he's from, so when he got `points = 168` then he will get`Great Friend` so this is the SQL that I've already have.

```
SELECT s.*
FROM customer_profiles t
INNER JOIN friend_levels s ON(t.friend_points >= s.points_needed)
WHERE s.points_needed = (SELECT max(f.points_needed)
                        FROM friend_levels f
                        WHERE t.friend_points >= f.points_needed)
AND t.user_id = $user_id
```

and result like this

[image]

so my question is how to get the next value of it in order to use it like this? For ex. If I am on the `Great Friend` level, then I have to get the `Best Friend` level.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be simple:

```
SELECT (SELECT min(fl.points_needed) 
          FROM friend_levels fl
         WHERE fl.points_needed > cp.friend_points) - cp.friend_points AS points_needed_for_next_level
  FROM customer_profiles cp
 WHERE cp.user_id = $user_id;
```